# C#: Check if string is contained in a string separated by commas

Tags: c#, string, split, contains

I have a column in a table in a database where strings are stored in the form: `1,5,10`. In my application I want to check if a variable exists in this column.

If I check like this:

```
table.column.Contains(variable)
```

If `variable = 0` then I will get true because `10` contains `0` but its not correct.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
table.column.Split(',')
```

But how I can check if there is any part of the `table.column` string that is equal with the variable?

Comment: To be honest the real fix is to not store data in a DB like that.  Instead a separate table with the values and a one-to-many relationship is what you'd want.

Comment: split would be the right way to do it. it also sounds like your db schema is flawed.

Comment: I know but cant change the DB schema.... Is there a solution for that schema?

Comment: having commas in column data is a poor design.

Comment: Also what is `table` if this is EF and you want the query to execute on the DB then `Split` isn't going to work.  You'd need to test the possibilities of it containing ",0," or starting with "0," or ending with ",0" or being equal to "0".

Comment: How about `(","+table.column+",").Contains("," + variable + ",")`? Broken design begets broken solutions.

Comment: Control-question: Does the string also contains spaces? `"1, 5,10"`?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen That fails to match at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Also, is this code supposed to run in pure .NET code, or is it part of an Entity Framework LINQ query or similar? (meaning, will it eventually be run as SQL or .NET?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `table.column` and `variable` are both `string` values, you can do this:

```
table.column.Split(',').Contains(variable)
```

Comment: This is the best way. A regex is possible but will be less clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are having is that when you do a split you are the results will be an an array of strings.  So tecincally contains 1 and contains 10 will both hit.   Assuming that your list is numbers you can do a split and cast them to numbers to fix this issue.

```
var sNumbers = "9,5,10";

var numbers = sNumbers.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).Contains(1);
```

This is of course only going to work if everything is a number

Comment: The OP didn't specify that everything in the string is necessarily an int

Comment: You don't need the `ToList` to do a `Contains`.

Comment: @MaxwellBurnham i know thats why i added the note at the bottom.  It appears that they are int though.